# Checking if values in each row/column are unique in vector

Tags: c++, vector, nested, duplicates

I'm trying to figure out how I can check each row & column to see if there are any duplicates of a number per column/row.

For example, say a 3x3 grid gets the following:

Grid:

```
{9, 7, 9}

{9, 6, 8}

{5, 1, 4}
```

The first row has a duplicate of 9 and the first column also has a duplicate of 9.

How can I solve these problems?

Comment: Is there a value that can *never* be in your matrix? Like e.g. `-1`? Then you can use that as a sentinel and have check for it when you check for duplicates.

Comment: It's unclear what do you do with the "blocked" fields, i.e. how do you "re-roll" the values. Maybe you could just create a separate nxn bool structure with flags which ones are "blocked"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**unordered_set**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/) data structure to solve the problem for checking duplicates. Its based on `hashtable data structure`. The good thing about it is that we can search for a particular element in **constant time O(1)**. Read about it more [**here**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

You need to have `n` `unordered_set` data structures. So its better to have a `vector` that will contain `unordered_set`.

Define a vector to contain `n` `unordered_set`:

```
vector<unordered_set<int>> mySets(n);
```

Now I am assuming that you block a particular value using value `0`, But this assumption is only true if `0` **does not originally appear in your grid**.

So basically we have a `unordered_set` for each of the columns and before inserting an element at position `(i,j)` in jth `unordered_set`, we check if the jth `unordered_set` contains it or not, if it does and its **not 0**, then our grid has not reached the solution. And for the rows we keep just one `unordered_set`, `mySet` which is cleared after traversing each row.

Now you can implement your `checkSolution()` method like this:

```
bool checkSolution()
{
   unordered_set<int> mySet;//for each row
   for (size_t i=0;i<myGrid.size();i++)
   {

       for (size_t j=0;j<myGrid[i].size();j++)
       {
           if(mySets[j].find(myGrid[i][j]) != mySets[j].end() && myGrid[i][j] != 0)
            return false;
           else
            mySets[j].insert(myGrid[i][j]);
           if(mySet.find(myGrid[i][j]) != mySet.end() && myGrid[i][j] != 0)  
            return false;
           else 
            mySet.insert(myGrid[i][j]);
       }

       mySet.clear();
   }
   return true;
}
```

You can also implement a solution where you have just one `unordered_set` for the columns and `n` `unordered_set` for each rows, but then you have to traverse the grid in column major order.

Following is a sample program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<unordered_set>

using namespace std;
bool checkSolution();
int myGrid[3][3] = {{0,2,3},
                    {4,5,6},
                    {0,8,9}};// 0 indicates blocked values


int main()
{
   if(checkSolution())
    cout<<"No duplicates exist";
   else cout<<"Duplicates exist";

}
bool checkSolution()
{
    int n = 3;
    vector<unordered_set<int> > mySets(n);
    unordered_set<int> mySet;
    for(int i = 0;i  < sizeof(myGrid)/sizeof(myGrid[0]); ++i)
    {
       for(int j = 0;j < sizeof(myGrid[i])/sizeof(myGrid[0][0]);++j)
       {
           if(mySets[j].find(myGrid[i][j]) != mySets[j].end() && myGrid[i][j] != 0)
               return false;
           else mySets[j].insert(myGrid[i][j]);
           if(mySet.find(myGrid[i][j]) != mySet.end() && myGrid[i][j] != 0)
               return false;
           else mySet.insert(myGrid[i][j]);
       }
       mySet.clear();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @chariked Well, you yourself mentioned that if n is the user input and we have a grid of nxn.

Comment: @chariked So basically n will be the number of columns( which is also equal to number of rows).

Comment: Oh ok, just wanted to make sure. Thanks

Comment: @chariked for which line are you getting this error?

Comment: @chariked you mean this line vector<unordered_set<int>> mySets(n); gives error

Comment: @chariked can you paste your code where u get the error

Comment: @chariked Ok, Im going to post my code. Then you can compare where you might have a different code.